# Difference between writing statements in definitions and in rules parts in lex

Tags: c, lex, lexical-analysis

I am new to lex. Assume the aim is to write a lex program to count the number of words. We should declare a int variable counter and increment it every time a words is seen. The question is what is the difference between these code samples:

```
%option main
%{ 
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 
             int i = 0;
%} 

%%
([a-zA-Z0-9])+    {i++;}
%%
```

and

```
%option main
%{ 
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 
%} 
%%
             int i = 0;
([a-zA-Z0-9])+    {i++;}
%%
```

and

```
%option main
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 
            int i = 0;
%%
([a-zA-Z0-9])+    {i++;}
%%
```

Do the places of `#include<stdio.h> #include<string.h>` affect the code here?
Does the program change depending on the place we declare integer the variable `i`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, order matters. But it's not the `#include` lines which are the issue here.

Here's one correct way to write this program:

```
%option main
/* The %{ and %} delimiters must be at the beginning of the line.
   Lines between %{ and %} are copied verbatim into the generated
   file, near to the beginning.
*/
%{ 
  #include <stdio.h> 
  #include <string.h>
%} 
%%
  /* These lines must be indented. Indented lines after the %% and
   * before the first rule are inserted verbatim into the generated
   * lexer right at the beginning of the definition of the function
   * yylex. This lets you declare local variables, like nwords.
   */
  int nwords = 0;
([a-zA-Z0-9])+    { ++nwords; }
  /* Other rules go here. Every possible input should be matched by
   * some rule.
   */

  /* At a minimum, you can ignore all unmatched characters
   * using the following fall back (which should be the last rule).
   */
.|\n              ;

<<EOF>>           { printf("%d words found.\n", nwords);
                    return 0; /* Let the caller know we're done */
                  }
```

The `<<EOF>>` rule is needed here to print out the number of words, because `nwords` will not be available outside of `yylex`. An alternative is to make `nwords` a global variable, but global variables are usually considered a bad idea. (And anyway you are using `%option main`, which means that you're not going to write the `main()` function so there is no other logical place to report the word count.

If you wanted to make `nwords` global, you would declare `nwords` in the `%{...%}` block, so that it is declared outside of any function.

Flex lets you leave out `%{` and `%}` as long as the code to be inserted is indented. But that's quite fragile and will confuse many people reading your code; it's definitely recommended that you use the delimiters, and then you don't have to worry about whether the inserted code is indented or not.

Comment: You probably also want a `.|\n   ;` rule to ignore other characters rather than echoing them...